Parse Powershell table to json object in Javascript
I am using Powershell to get the Windows Drive properties using the command wmic diskdrive.
The resulting table is taken care of by some JavaScript code. I want to create an array of JSON objects, with each item the properties of a drive.
The Powershell command to achieve this is wmic diskdrive | ConvertTo-Json. However, on the Windows machine where I am using this command, Powershell v1.0 is installed, while the command ConvertTo-Json is only available from v3.0. Updating the Powershell to the newest version is not an option. How do I convert this table to a JSON object in JavaScript (NodeJS)?
